# Excel VBA code midStr() function using left and right position instead of length used with mid()

Tags: strings, vba, excel

In the early days of Basic (1970's when i started coding) the midStr() function used left and right positions directly rather than left and length we now use with mid(). I always found it more efficient in my mind to code using the old midStr() method, so I finally just created some code to do it. It's certainly not as efficient as mid(), and if I am dealing with lots of data I'd use mid() directly instead, but for simplicity, I do like the old way better, it's more direct to simply code rightPos rather then rightpos - leftPos + 1, and to test for null.

I also made the rightPos optional, and when not used, the length of the textin is used instead, so it will simply return the remainder of the text starting at the leftPos.

Any kind critique is welcome, thank you.

```
Function midStr(ByVal textin As String, _
                ByVal leftPos As Long, _
       Optional ByVal rightPos As Variant) As Variant
   'midStr returns textin string using leftPos and rightPos (rather than num_chars).
   'rightPos is optional, len(textin) is used for the rightPos when it's not otherwise defined.
  
   On Error GoTo midStrErr
   If IsMissing(rightPos) Then rightPos = Len(textin)
   If rightPos < leftPos Then
      midStr = vbNullString
   Else
      midStr = Mid(textin, leftPos, rightPos - leftPos + 1)
   End If
   Exit Function
 
midStrErr:
   On Error Resume Next
   midStr = CVErr(xlErrValue) '#VALUE!
End Function
```

Comment: It is interesting that `midStr("Hello World", 2, 4)` returns `ell`.  I would have thought that it would return 2 characters.  Not character 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 5):

While the `Optional ByVal rightPos As Variant` is a cool idea because you can use the `IsMissing` function, it introduces unnecessary errors. For example, `Debug.Print midStr("Hello World", 1, Nothing)` will print "Error 2015" in the Immediate window. That line should not be allowed to compile.

I would declare the `rightPos` parameter as `Long`. The compiler will take care of some of the issues - for example you won't be able to pass an Object. The `Long` will default to 0 so you can replace `If IsMissing(rightPos) Then rightPos = Len(textin)` with `If rightPos = 0 Then rightPos = Len(textin)`.

The generally accepted convention in VBA is that method names are written with `PascalCase` and variable names are written with `camelCase`. Moreover, an Excel User Defined Function (UDF) is usually written with UPPERCASE.

This function seems to be designed as an Excel UDF. What if you need to use it in VBA? The Excel errors mean nothing to another VBA method. I would write this as a separate VBA only function that will work in any VBA-capable application host (no need to return a Variant):

```
Public Function MidStr(ByVal textin As String, _
                       ByVal leftPos As Long, _
              Optional ByVal rightPos As Long _
) As String
    Const methodName As String = "MidStr"
    
    If leftPos < 0 Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid left position"
    If rightPos < 0 Then Err.Raise 5, methodName, "Invalid right position"
    
    If rightPos = 0 Then rightPos = Len(textin)
    If rightPos < leftPos Then
        MidStr = vbNullString
    Else
        MidStr = VBA.Mid$(textin, leftPos, rightPos - leftPos + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

I would then have an Excel UDF:

```
Public Function MID_STR(ByVal textin As String, _
                        ByVal leftPos As Long, _
               Optional ByVal rightPos As Long _
) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    MID_STR = MidStr(textin, leftPos, rightPos)
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    MID_STR = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

This allows the use of `MidStr` function in other VBA methods and the `MID_STR` is only going to be called via the Excel interface.

Comment: Raising a runtime error from a public function invoked from a worksheet cell would have Excel swallow the error and the cell would contain a `#VALUE!` error, without needing to explicitly return `CVErr(xlErrValue)`. Not sure duplicating the function is a good idea, basically - upvoted for everything else!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, but dangeerous if you call the UDF using the ```Evaluate``` method from VBA (for whatever reason). Always best to make sure no error is raised within a UDF. An error raised during an ``Evaluate`` call will stop any VBA code in it's track.

Comment: ...and that would be the *expected* behavior, yes :) the most likely outcome otherwise is a *type mismatch* resulting from capturing the return value into a `String` and getting a `Variant/Error` into it - throwing from the guard clauses would point to the real cause of the problem without any indirection.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It is, I won't argue with that, but there are cases where one would want to make sure that the ```Evaluate``` call does not kill VBA without gracefully cleaning up. It's a matter of coding style I guess

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will take the advice given by many to use StartIndex and EndIndex instead of LeftPos and RightPos. My current design allows any number to pass, and as long as StartPos <= EndPos then some character(s) will be returned, if not then NULL. But, I agree, defaulting to zero eliminates some error potential, and it does not limit the code at all, so I'll make that change. I also really appreciate the comments regarding PascalCase vs camelCase vs UPPER_CASE. I've never seen a dialog on the subject and so I plan to change to what is more standard.

Answer (score 2):

### Pascal Case

When I first started code, Hungarian Notations was a widely accepted standard for VBA. Over the years, Camel Case took over.  In my opinion, it is time for Pascal Case to become the standard.

This has been my rant for some time. I welcome a debate from all user from noob to MVP.  The following snippet exemplifies my argument:

```
Dim value As Range
value = Range("A1").value

Dim text As String
text = Range("A1").text
```

Using Camel Casing to name a variable changes the casing for all properties and methods that share the name for the whole project.  I've answer over 2000 question in forum over the years.  I can't tell you how many times the improper casing threw me off.  It is ridiculous that Microsoft never fixed it.

### Function Signature

> ```
> Function midStr(ByVal textin As String, _
>                 ByVal leftPos As Long, _
>        Optional ByVal rightPos As Variant) As Variant
> ```

As Cristian Buse mentioned rightPos should be typed Long and the function itself should return a string.  I would add that `rightPos` is rather confusing.

> *used left and right positions directly rather than left and length

When I first read this, I thought: "midStr returns a string using the Left() and Right() functions.  How peculiar.  I wonder how this is easier than mid"   **WRONG!!**  As it turns out it it use the starting and ending position to return a substring.  That's great, I love it!

I would recommend calling the function `SubString` but it's named after a vintage VB function.   Fo me, it would be better if it returned 1 less character like most similar substring functions.

`leftPos` and `rightPos` on the other hand they have got to go.  It's too confusing, especially because the function already behaves a little different than expect by returning the extra character.  I would use `start` and `end` if they were not reserved words.  `StartIndex` and `EndIndex` or `pStart` and `pEnd` are much more intuitive to me.

Function MidStr(ByVal Text As String, ByVal StartIndex As Long, Optional ByVal EndIndex As Variant) As String
'midStr returns text string using startIndex and endIndex (rather than num_chars).
'endIndex is optional, len(text) is used for the endIndex when it's not otherwise defined.

```
   On Error GoTo midStrErr
   If EndIndex = 0 Then EndIndex = Len(Text)
   If EndIndex < StartIndex Then
      MidStr = vbNullString
   Else
      MidStr = Mid(Text, StartIndex, EndIndex - StartIndex + 1)
   End If
   Exit Function
 
midStrErr:
   On Error Resume Next
   MidStr = CVErr(xlErrValue) '#VALUE!
End Function
```

Comment: I've semi-recently adopted `PascalCaseEverywhere` and haven't looked back since (had adopted `camelCaseForLocals` from years of C# influencing my VB style!). As for MS fixing it, I could be wrong but my understanding is that it's not something that's possible without rewriting how VBA caches in-scope names ...to make them case-sensitive.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you would know better that I do.  I suspect that they originally did this to improve performance.  In truth, I would hate to be the one responsible for fixing this nuisance and taking the heat for any new bug that comes along.  Thanks for the ↑vote↑.

Comment: To be fair, having a clean source control diff wasn't much of a concern back then :)

Comment: Indeed, absolutely annoying to have VBA lowercasing method names because a variable with same name is defined somewhere or vice versa. I found myself adding a _ at the end of the common variable names (value_, key_) but is ugly and I don't like it. I will consider PascalCase for everything

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will take the advice given by many to use StartIndex and EndIndex instead of LeftPos and RightPos. My current design allows any number to pass, and as long as StartPos <= EndPos then some character(s) will be returned, if not then NULL. But, I agree, defaulting to zero eliminates some error potential, and it does not limit the code at all, so I'll make that change. I also really appreciate the comments regarding PascalCase vs camelCase vs UPPER_CASE. I've never seen a dialog on the subject and so I plan to change to what is more standard.

Comment: @MarkMain I have one caveat to using Pascal Case.  I do not use it for simple counters.  For counters I use r and c for rows and columns lowercase letters for everything else.

Comment: thanks, I do the same thing, i typically use r and c for the row and columns; i tend to use i, and i2 for simple indexing, and i'll generally just use 'a' for any quick string manipulation. single letters are nice when it's obvious they are used in a short block of code. I notice that the parameters for Excel use all lower_case with the underscore, and the name of the function seems to be all upper case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this conforms to a more standard style, i am using start_num, all in lower_case, because that is what i find in the MID() function.
I want the code clean and short. As always, I appreciate any helpful feedback. Thank you in advance.

```
Function MIDSTR(ByVal textin As String, _
                ByVal start_num As Long, _
       Optional ByVal end_num As Long = -1) As String
   'MIDSTR() is similar to MID() except it returns textin string using start_num and end_num instead of using num_chars.
   'end_num is optional, Len(textin) is used for the end_num when it's not otherwise defined or when end_enum is a negative number.
   'Null is returned when start_num is greater than end_num.
  
    If end_num < 0 Then end_num = Len(textin)
    If start_num > end_num Then
        MIDSTR = vbNullString
    Else
        MIDSTR = Mid(textin, start_num, end_num - start_num + 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: (moderator hat on) Since the site has to adhere to its Q&A format (and also because actual "answer" posts can go much more in-depth than any comment), it would be better to re-frame this "answer" (it's technically flaggable as "not an answer") as a [follow-up question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/23788). Cheers!

Comment: (moderator hat off) I'd make the function explicitly `Public` and either 1) use language-standard `PascalCase` and return a `String` to leverage VBA error handling (cells get `#VALUE!`), or 2) use the Excel-inspired `SCREAMCASE` and return a `Variant` to emphasize intended use as a UDF. Do you know about Rubberduck?

Comment: [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) inspections would flag the implicit/default access modifier, and would suggest using the stringly-typed `Mid$` function over the variant-returning `Mid`, for example. And you could reword that comment into a `@Description` annotation just above the procedure, and then that documentation string could appear in the *Object Browser*.